# How to find a attribute which associated with multiple value of another attribute in dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am doing data cleaning and want to perform conflict resolution of an attribute. Conflict resolution is to find conflicting attributes in the tuples referring to the same real-world entity and find the true values for these attributes. For example, tuples referring to the same person may have different values in age, but only one value should be chosen.

I have Csv file which has 'Branch' and 'City' attribute, what I am looking for the records having the same Branch name but have different City which definitely a buggy record and then to correct it by replacing with most frequent value associated with that attribute. As of now, I have used group by to know the count but not able to proceed further:

```
df = read_csv(File source)
df.groupby(['Branch','City']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

[Output of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFyyQ.png)

From above output, we know that Branch 'A' has two record associated with wrong city, and need to replace the city  with 'Yangaon' as it is the most frequent value for branch 'A'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try:

```py
most_frequent_cities=df.groupby(['Branch']).Count.idxmax(axis=1)
df2=df.iloc[list(most_frequent_cities)].reset_index(drop=True)
df2
```

Output:

```py
Branch  City    Count
0   A   Yangon  292
1   B   Mandalay    289
2   C   Naypyitaw   289
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This, not the output I am looking for, your code will simply drop the row in which branch is associated with multiple cities

Comment: If any one can tell how to get the branch name which mulpile entries  in the output  shared in the question?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to perform the `groupby` to the `DataFrame` with only duplicated branch, for example:

```py
In [35]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[35]: 
         0      1
0  branch1  city1
1  branch2  city2
2  branch1  city3
3  branch1  city4

In [36]: grouped_df = df[df.duplicated(0, keep=False)].groupby(by=0)                                                                                                                                               

In [37]: for key, item in grouped_df: 
    ...:     print(grouped_df.get_group(key), "\n\n") 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                           
         0      1
0  branch1  city1
2  branch1  city3
3  branch1  city4 

In [38]: grouped_df.groups # get branch name with index instead                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[38]: {'branch1': Int64Index([0, 2, 3], dtype='int64')}
```

It can be seen that you need to filter the `df` first with `df.duplicated(col_name, keep=False)`, then `groupby(by=col_name)`. What this `keep=False` do is to retain all of the value in which duplicates occurs (not ignoring the first or last one, the default is ignoring the first one).

Hope this helps.